# Running Jest within Electron and using --inspect-brk

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron, jestjs, ts-jest

I am trying to get Jest to run within the Electron runtime (rather than Node), it works as expected when I start Electron as follows:

```
$ node_modules/.bin/electron node_modules/.bin/jest
 PASS  src/index.spec.ts
  index
    ✓ should export a type named: `C` (2ms)
    ✓ can change X via `setX` and retrieve X using `getX`

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.912s
Ran all test suites.
```

However when I try to run Electron with debugging enabled, Jest fails to detect any of the unit tests:

```
$ node_modules/.bin/electron --inspect-brk node_modules/.bin/jest
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/16848549-d2de-4798-815c-5475156c961e
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
```

At this point I use `chrome://inspect` to attach a Node debugger session, the session is paused in the debugger, and once I hit the Resume script execution button the following output appears:

```
Debugger attached.
No tests found, exiting with code 1
Run with `--passWithNoTests` to exit with code 0
In /Users/cdivilly/work/ts/TypeScript-Babel-Starter-master
  12 files checked.
  testMatch: **/__tests__/**/*.[jt]s?(x), **/?(*.)+(spec|test).[tj]s?(x) - 1 match
  testPathIgnorePatterns: /node_modules/ - 12 matches
  testRegex:  - 0 matches
Pattern: node_modules/.bin/jest - 0 matches
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
```

- This time Jest fails to find any unit tests.
- How come adding `--inspect-brk` changes the behaviour of Jest?

If I instead use node to run with debugging enabled that also works fine:

```
$ node --inspect-brk node_modules/.bin/jest
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/60902f16-acac-442a-a82c-40c9e0fd4857
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
 PASS  src/index.spec.ts
...
```

If I use `--inspect` instead of `--inspect-brk` that fails in the same manner:

```
$ node_modules/.bin/electron --inspect node_modules/.bin/jest
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/4a003d44-d958-4e4c-b8d5-b0ff5db29ce4
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
No tests found, exiting with code 1
Run with `--passWithNoTests` to exit with code 0
In /Users/cdivilly/work/ts/TypeScript-Babel-Starter-master
  12 files checked.
  testMatch: **/__tests__/**/*.[jt]s?(x), **/?(*.)+(spec|test).[tj]s?(x) - 1 match
  testPathIgnorePatterns: /node_modules/ - 12 matches
  testRegex:  - 0 matches
Pattern: node_modules/.bin/jest - 0 matches
```

So it seems to be the specific intersection of the Electron runtime, Jest and enabling debugging that causes this issue.

For reference here is the source code for my example, which is forked from [TypeScript-Babel-Starter](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-Babel-Starter). I am writing my code and tests in Typescript, and using `ts-jest` as the Jest preset.

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "babel-typescript-sample",
  "version": "0.7.1",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "type-check": "tsc --noEmit",
    "type-check:watch": "npm run type-check -- --watch",
    "build": "npm run build:types && npm run build:js",
    "build:types": "tsc --emitDeclarationOnly",
    "build:js": "babel src --out-dir lib --extensions \".ts,.tsx\" --source-maps inline",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.4.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.4.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.1",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.3.3",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.19",
    "electron": "6.1.1",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "ts-jest": "^24.1.0",
    "typescript": "^3.3.3"
  }
}
```

### jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  collectCoverage: true
};
```

### index.spec.ts

```
import * as index from './index'

describe('index', () => {
    it('should export a type named: `C`',() => {
     expect(typeof index.C).toBe('function')
    })
    it('can change X via `setX` and retrieve X using `getX`',() => {
        let c = new index.C();
        expect(c.getX()).toBe(10)
        c.setX(20)
        expect(c.getX()).toBe(20)
    })
})
```

### index.ts

```
export class C {
    private x = 10
    getX = () => this.x;
    setX = (newVal: number) => { this.x = newVal; }
}

export let x = new C();
export let y = { ...{ some: "value" } }
```

Comment: Running Jest using `--runInBand` makes no difference to the outcome. Nor does adding `--no-cache`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Unfortunately, I cannot provide an actual solution to your problem, but I think I examined its cause:</s> See end of answer for a workaround.

The Node.js executable hides its options from the executed JS file. So if you run `node --inspect file.js`, the `process.argv` array will be `['/path/to/node', '/path/to/file.js']`, without the `--inspect` flag appearing anywhere.

Electron however will not do the same. The `process.argv` array differs between `node_modules/.bin/electron file.js` and `node_modules/.bin/electron --inspect file.js`.

Jest seems to take all arguments from the third onwards and use them as its own options. That means, when you run `node_modules/.bin/electron --inspect node_modules/.bin/jest`, Jest will use the `node_modules/.bin/jest` argument as a test file pattern — and not find any that match it. That's also why your test output states: `Pattern: node_modules/.bin/jest - 0 matches`.

**EDIT:**

I found a terribly inelegant workaround, but it solves the problem.

You can create a "proxy" file which removes the `--inspect` argument from `process.argv` and run your tests through that:

```
// test.js
if (['--inspect', '--inspect-brk'].includes(process.argv[1])) {
  process.argv.splice(1, 1)
}

require('./node_modules/.bin/jest')
```

Running `electron test.js` will run Jest tests successfully, `electron --inspect test.js` will do so as well. Since the Electron binary itself is independent from the script it executes, it will still find the `--inspect` flag and go into debug mode.

Comment: Thanks Loilo, had just gotten as far as figuring out that the command-line was being parsed differently, cheers for the workaround